# How to put Array value to Database on dbSqlite?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

My project used to save products information into shoppingCart on a database with `dbSqlite`. But, for now it should save information of product from server. According to web service, one variable type is `List Array`. It was `String` before. And one of them is `double`, it was `String` also. I changed `real` in `dbSqlite` but what I should do for `Array`? How can save it on dbSqlite again?

> error: no suitable method found for put(String,List) method
>   ContentValues.put(String,String) is not applicable

Cart.java

```
public class Cart {
    private List<String> Image;
    private String Title;
    private double Cost;
    private String Market;

    public List<String> getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(List<String> image) {
        Image = image;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return Cost;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost) {
        Cost = cost;
    }

    private String TotalCost;
    private String Description;

    public boolean boolExpand = false;

    boolean isExpanded;


    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return this.isExpanded;
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.isExpanded = expanded;
    }




    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }



    public String getMarket() {
        return Market;
    }

    public void setMarket(String market) {
        Market = market;
    }

    public String getTotalCost() {
        return TotalCost;
    }

    public void setTotalCost(String totalCost) {
        TotalCost = totalCost;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }
}

ProductDetailAdapter.java



public class ProductDetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductDetailAdapter.ViewHolder> {
 btnProductDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
                // isLogined bilgisi shared preferences'tan alınıyor. eğer true ise username ve password bilgileri alınıyor.
                // değil ise empty olarak giriliyor.
                isLogined = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLogined", false);
                if (isLogined) {
                    saveCartAmount();
                    db = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
                    List<String> img;
                    double cost;
                    String title;
                    String total;
                    String market;
                    String description;
                    img = productPageList.get(position).getProductImages();
                    cost = productPageList.get(position).getProductPrices().get(position).getShopProductPrice();
                    title = productPageList.get(position).getProductName();
                    market = productPageList.get(position).getProductPrices().get(position).getShopName();
                    total = "";
                    description = productPageList.get(position).getProductDescription();
                    // Log.e("amountdb","dasdsa");
                    //  amount = amountdb++;

                    db.AddToCart(img, title, cost, market, total, description);

                    cartListener.onProductSelect(productPageList.get(position));

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ürün sepetinize eklendi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Sepete ürün eklemek için üye girişi yapmanız gerekmektedir.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
   }
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "Login.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       db.execSQL("Create table cart(Image text, Title text, Cost real, Market text, TotalCost text, Description text)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

      db.execSQL("drop table if exists cart");
    }

    public void deleteCart(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("cart", null,null);
    }
    public void AddToCart(List<String> Image, String Title, Double Cost, String Market, String TotalCost, String Descritpion){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues data = new ContentValues();

        data.put("Image",Image );
        data.put("Title",Title);
        data.put("Cost",Cost);
        data.put("Market",Market);
        data.put("TotalCost", TotalCost);
        data.put("Description", Descritpion);

        db.insert("cart",null,data);

    }

    public List<Cart> getdata(){
        // DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();
        List<Cart> data=new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor rs =  db.rawQuery( "select * from cart",null);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Cart dataModel = null;
        while (rs.moveToNext()) {
            dataModel= new Cart();
            List<String> image = Collections.singletonList(rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Image")));
            String title = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Title"));
            Double cost = (rs.getDouble(rs.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Cost")));
            String market = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Market"));
            String totalCost = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TotalCost"));
            String description = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Description"));

            dataModel.setImage(image);
            dataModel.setTitle(title);
            dataModel.setCost(cost);
            dataModel.setMarket(market);
            dataModel.setTotalCost(totalCost);
            dataModel.setDescription(description);
            stringBuffer.append(dataModel);
            data.add(dataModel);
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried serializing the list to String, then save it in a TEXT field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the array like this :

```
String[] myArray = `put your array here`
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++)
{
 //Here u insert the data by getting what u need from the array
 data.put("Cost",myArray.get(i).Cost);
}
```

Comment: `db.execSQL("Create table cart(Image text, Title text, Cost real, Market text, TotalCost text, Description text)");`  How I should do image in here? It can be `text`? Or I should change to `Blob`?

Comment: if u save the image directly in db as 'Blob' , and if the image u get is the `link` of the image , then u have to get that image first and then save it . but i don't recommend doing that , the better way is to store the link of the image in the db and save the image in folder

Comment: What is ur image field type in db?

Comment: It's text and I get as array from server.

Comment: if the DB field is text , then u have to download the image to a (folder) and save (image name) in the DB , then when u want to show that image , u just put the path to that folder and then get image name from db to complete the path for example `imagesfolder/my_image_from_db.jpg` , but why u get images array ? is it many images ? , if there is many images in the image array , then u can use the code i put above to get the images one by one , but instead of put them directly to DB , u will have to download the image and put it in folder like

Comment: Yes its many images. But, it will be link. I don't need that database. Only I want it for sopping cart and show in cart page. Actually, I need one image to show in cart. So, Thats enough for me only save one image in db. So I have to serialize for it?

Comment: Ok. I solved like that. thanks for helping. I will upvote your answer.

Comment: ur welcome , i was going to put downloading image code for u , but if u solved it , then no need i guess , happy for u and GL .

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine serializing the list to string. I. e. you could serialize it to json and deserialize it if you need it again.

Here is a small code example for two functions you could use in your DatabaseHelper.

```
private String serialize(List<String) list) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for (String s : list) {
        jsonArray.put(s);
    }
    return jsonArray.toString();
}

private List<String> deserialize(String json) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.getLength(); ++i) {
        list.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
    }
    return list;
}
```

And then you can use these functions:

```
data.put("Image",serialize(Image));

List<String> image = deserialize(rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Image")));
```

*(This is only pseudo-code. Maybe you need to adjust it. Furthermore the functions don't handle null-parameters and may throw NullPointerExceptions!)*

Comment: I don't have problem to get data from server. Only problem I should need to put on database with new variable type. This Cart model only using to put data on sqlite database.